# Turn off hard drive programmatically

Tags: windows, vds

When I call [IVdsDiskOnline::Offline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), disk becomes offline and its volumes disappear from the system.

Does the physical HDD continue spinning, wasting energy and wearing the hardware?

If yes, how do I stop it?

If it matters, I’m using an average desktop PC with Intel® 9 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller, and SATA HDD.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wear is not significantly induced by keeping the drive on (assuming a good thermal situation).  Start/stop cycles, on the other hand, do wear the drive noticeably.  (Many smart estimates allow 600k restarts, Google saw a slightly higher failure rate allowing restarts vs always on).

Comment: Well, my #1 priority wasn't wear, it was spin on delays. Here’s the project page, BTW: https://turnoffhdd.codeplex.com/ and it works more or less OK. However minimizing wear would also be nice.